# Searching for XElement with attribute name that contain hyphens/dashes

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I wrote some code in VB.Net a while ago that is using XElement, XDocument, etc... to store and manipulate HTML.  Some of the HTML makes use of attribute names that contain a hyphen/dash (-).  I encountered issues using LinqToXml to search for XElements by these attributes.

Back then I found an article (can't find it now) that indicated the solution in VB.net was to use syntax like this:

```
Dim rootElement as XElement = GetARootXElement()
Dim query = From p In rootElement.<div> Where p.@<data-qid> = 5 Select p
```

The "magic" syntax is the @<> which somehow translates the hyphenated attribute name into a format that can be successfully used by Linq.  This code works great in VB.Net.

The problem is that we have now converted all the VB.Net code to C# and the conversion utility choked on this syntax.  I can't find anything about this "magic" syntax in VB.Net and so I was hoping someone could fill in the details for me, specifically, what the C# equivalent is.  Thanks.

Here is an example:

```
<div id='stuff'>
    <div id='stuff2'>
        <div id='stuff' data-qid=5>
            <!-- more html -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code above the rootElement would be the stuff div and I would want to search for the inner div with the attribuate data-qid=5.

Comment: Can you provide sample xml which you are trying to parse?

Comment: I added an example to the original post.

Comment: There is no quotes around data-qid attribute value? And what value you are trying to parse?

Comment: That "magic" syntax looks like an XML Literal in VB.NET.  I don't believe there is an equivalent in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the XML Literal.  Didn't know about.  Also, I messed up that HTML example the stuff in the inner most div was supposed to be stuff3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the following to compile in C# - I think it's equivalent to the original VB (note that the original VB had Option Strict Off):

```
XElement rootElement = GetARootXElement();
var query = from p in rootElement.Elements("div")
            where p.Attribute("data-qid").Value == 5.ToString()
            select p;
```

Here's my (revised) test, which finds the div with the 'data-qid' attribute:

```
var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<div id='stuff'><div id='stuff2'><div id='stuff3' data-qid='5'><!-- more html --></div></div></div>");
var rootElement = xml.Element("div");
var query = from p in rootElement.Elements("div")
    where p.Attribute("data-qid").Value == 5.ToString()
    select p;
```

Comment: It did have Option Strict Off, which I left out because I figured it didn't matter.  I have also been able to get this to compile, but it doesn't seem to find the div with the data-qid attribute.  The linq query returns nothing in both VB.net and C# unless you use the cool Html literal.

Comment: See my 'full test' - I had to user '5' instead of 5 in the initialization of the 'xml' variable.

Comment: I put that code in to a console app and had it output the query.Count() and it's 0.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the LINQ query, but I can't find it.

Comment: See my revised test - it now has a count of 1.

Comment: You are correct.  In fact, I even changed the 5.ToString() to "5" and it still worked.  This is the best of both worlds, I don't have to include another dependency and I can keep all my other code that uses data-qid.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (available from NuGet) to parse HTML. Here is an example:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("index.html");
var innerDiv = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='stuff']/*/div[@data-qid=5]");
```

This XPath query gets inner `div` tag which has `data-qid` equal to `5`. Also outer `div` should have id equal to `'stuff'`. And here is the way to get `data-qid` attribute value:

```
var qid = innerDiv.Attributes["data-qid"].Value; // 5
```

Comment: Does HtmlAgilityPack let me parse Html that is not coming from a file?  Can I simply load it from a string or something similar?

Comment: The answer to that question is yes: doc.LoadHtml(string).  That xpath query (is that xpath?) didn't return anything; however, this did:  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@data-qid='5']");  So I believe that will solve my problem.  I have it working in a test app, let's see how it works in the real app.

Comment: @DovanRogars sorry, was offline. Yes, you are using correct method of loading xml string. And my xpath query worked on your sample data, even without quotes around data-qid attribute

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using HtmlAgilityPack offered by Sergey Berezovskiy, there's easier way to do without it by using XmlPath's Extensions class, containing extension methods to work with LINQ to XML:

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
var xml = XElement.Parse(html);
var innderDiv = xml.XPathSelectElement("//div[@id='stuff' and @data-qid=5]");
```