# Operator 'Like' is not defined for types 'System.Xml.Linq.XName' and 'String'

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml, operators

I need to retrieve the element name that is like this "*-Font" and then retrieve the attribute values.

Here is the linq used...

```
Dim categories = From dc as xelement In Xml.DescendantsAndSelf("defaults") _
let Id = lw.name _
Where Id = "*-Font" _
let FontFamily = lw.attribute("font-family").value _
let FontSize = lw.attribute("font-size").value _
Select Id, FontFamily, FontSize
```

Here is the xml sample...

```
<defaults>
    <scaling>1</scaling>
    <page-layout>2</page-layout>
    <system-layout>3</system-layout>
    <appearance>4</appearance>
    <default-font font-family="Arial" font-size="20.4"/>
    <word-font font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="10.2"/>
</defaults>
```

This query fails with...
Operator 'Like' is not defined for types 'System.Xml.Linq.XName' and 'String'.

I've done a net search and found nothing for Linq to xml and the Like operator.

Ok, so how can I retrieve all the element names Like "*-Font".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `lw.Name.LocalName.EndsWith("-font")`, but your LINQ query has `dc` and `lw`... and doesn't seem to compile.  Here is a complete example for what I think you are looking for:

```
Dim xml =
<defaults>
    <scaling>1</scaling>
    <page-layout>2</page-layout>
    <system-layout>3</system-layout>
    <appearance>4</appearance>
    <default-font font-family="Arial" font-size="20.4"/>
    <word-font font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="10.2"/>
</defaults>

Dim categories =
    From e In xml.Elements()
    Let Id = e.Name.LocalName
    Where Id.EndsWith("-font")
    Let FontFamily = e.Attribute("font-family").Value
    Let FontSize = e.Attribute("font-size").Value
    Select Id, FontFamily, FontSize
```

This results in:

```
Id              FontFamily        FontSize
--              ----------        --------
default-font    Arial             20.4
word-font       Times New Roman   10.2
```

**EDIT**

As shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202306/searching-for-xelement-with-attribute-name-that-contain-hyphens-dashes), you can use XML literals for the hyphenated attributes (I couldn't work that out initially, because `@font-family` doesn't work):

```
Dim categories =
    From e In xml.Elements()
    Let Id = e.Name.LocalName
    Where Id.EndsWith("-font")
    Let FontFamily = e.@<font-family>
    Let FontSize = e.@<font-size>
    Select Id, FontFamily, FontSize
```